# Please convert this cursor into CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fetching the Objectid from the Table with Cursor.
I need the same using CTE or any other way.

```
DECLARE  @TagID int,@ObjectID int,@ObjectTypeID int ,@UserAccountID int

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
  SELECT distinct TagID,ObjectID,ObjectTypeID,UserAccountID  FROM   taglink  WHERE  TagID in(1000528,1000482)      
    AND ObjectTypeID =5  and UserAccountID=1036144
OPEN curs
FETCH next FROM curs INTO @TagID, @ObjectId, @ObjectTypeID, @UserAccountID
CREATE TABLE #tagids  (TaglinkId INT,     TagId     INT ,ModifiedDate datetime )
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

      INSERT INTO #tagids(TaglinkId,TagId,ModifiedDate)
      SELECT TaglinkId,TagId,ModifiedDate      FROM   taglink      WHERE  UserAccountID = @UserAccountID   AND ObjectTypeID = @ObjectTypeID AND ObjectId = @ObjectId 
            and TagID not in (1000528,1000483,1000482) 
         and    TagID not in (select  TagId from #tagids)
            order by ModifiedDate desc

      FETCH next FROM curs INTO @TagID, @ObjectId, @ObjectTypeID, @UserAccountID
  END
SELECT * FROM   #tagids ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC
DROP TABLE #tagids

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Comment: Whats this tag `replay` ? syntax looks like for `sql-server` ?

Comment: This question needs more information, and exactly who's SQL dialect is this? Microsoft?  If it is tag is ms-sql or something like that.

Comment: microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eliminate the `cursor` by using `JOIN`. Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        TagId,
        ObjectID,
        ObjectTypeID,
        UserAccountID
    FROM taglink
    WHERE
        TagID IN(1000528,1000482)
        AND ObjectTypeID = 5
        AND UserAccountID = 1036144
)
INSERT INTO #tagids(TagLinkId, TagId, ModifiedDate)
SELECT
    tl.TagLinkId,
    tl.TagId,
    tl.ModifiedDate
FROM tagLink tl
INNER JOIN CTE c
    ON c.UserAccountID = tl.UserAccountID
    AND c.ObjectTypeID = tl.ObjectTypeID
    AND c.ObjectID = tl.ObjectID
WHERE
    tl.TagID NOT IN(1000528,1000483,1000482)
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT TagId FROM #tagids WHERE TagId = tl.TagId
    )
ORDER BY tl.ModifiedDate DESC
```